# How to get a ViewModel from a Worker class?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-workmanager

1. I have an `Activivity` in my application called MainActivity.
2. The MainActivity is associated with a `ViewModel` in the OnCreate method

   ```
   ...
   val someViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)
   ...
   ```
3. I do some background work with `Workers`.

   `val someWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LoginWorker>().build()
   WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork("SOMEWORK", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, captivePortalWork).enqueue()`
4. Here comes the issue...  The `worker` for example do a loop 10 times and in each time just sleep for a second... so we have a 10 seconds background work.
   I want to update the `ViewModel` to show the progress of the background work and uptade the UI each time.

   A) I can acces to the View model from the MainActivity and observe the `worker` but and I can only update the `ViewModel` when the progress are Succeded or Failed... that means I can show a progress when the work is 0 or 100% done.

   B) If I could access the ViewModel from the Worker class, I could update the ViewModel at any time. But I don't know how... this method doesn't work inside a Worker class.

   `val someWork = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)`

   **How can I get a `ViewModel` from a `Worker` class?**

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You cannot use a `ViewModel` for this. You need to use your own Room Database and expose a `LiveData` to your UI to show progress.

Comment: I am not sure how this is the correct answer but you DO NOT NEED Room Database to accomplish this. This is a way to do so but certainly not best practice for showing progress of a Worker class.

Answer (score 9):

You have to assign value from `Worker` output `Data` to `ViewModel`, and this data is observed in your `Activity`, like so:

code for Worker:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    public static final String MY_KEY_DATA_FROM_WORKER = "MY_KEY_DATA_FROM_WORKER";

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        //here do http or database requests
        String result = "my needed result";

        if (result != null) {
            setOutputData(new Data.Builder()
                    .putString(MY_KEY_DATA_FROM_WORKER, result)
                    .build());

            return Worker.Result.SUCCESS;
        }

        return Result.FAILURE;
    }
}
```

code for ViewModel:

```
 public class MyActivityModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> myLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();

    public void loadDataFromWorker(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        OneTimeWorkRequest myWorkerReq = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .build();

        WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
        mWorkManager
                .beginWith(myWorkerReq)
                .enqueue();

        mWorkManager.getStatusByIdLiveData(myWorkerReq.getId()).observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<WorkStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WorkStatus workStatus) {
                if (workStatus.getState().isFinished()) {

                    // here you asign data to ViewModel
                    Data workOutputData = workStatus.getOutputData();
                    myLiveData.setValue(workOutputData.getString(MyWorker .MY_KEY_DATA_FROM_WORKER));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
  }
```

Code for Activity:

```
//...

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    //declare model and start loading data in Worker
    MyActivityModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyActivityModel.class);
    model.loadDataFromWorker(this);

    //observe data from model
    model.getData().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String str) {

        //here you get new String value or null if Work failed 

        }
    });
}

//...
```

Comment: Say that you don't want so simple data as a string to be sent from the worker to the viewmodel but instead, the whole http response, say a List of custom objects. How do you achieve that? Thanks

Comment: WorkManager.getInstance() is now deprecated, Please use  WorkManager.getInstance(context),replace LifecycleOwner with context

Answer (score 4):

In short, you don't want to expose your `ViewModel` to `WorkManager` or `Worker` class, but instead, expose the percent to your `ViewModel`.

WorkManager 2.3.1+ added support for setting and observing intermediate progress.

> For Java developers using a ListenableWorker or a Worker, the setProgressAsync() API returns a ListenableFuture; updating progress is asynchronous, given that the update process involves storing progress information in a database. In Kotlin, you can use the CoroutineWorker object's setProgress() extension function to update progress information.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress)

For Kotlin, use `CoroutineWorker` with the following:

```
companion object {
    const val Progress = "Progress"
    private const val delayDuration = 1L
}

override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    val firstUpdate = workDataOf(Progress to 0)
    val lastUpdate = workDataOf(Progress to 100)
    setProgress(firstUpdate)
    delay(delayDuration)
    setProgress(lastUpdate)
    return Result.success()
}
```

In your `ViewModel`, you can observe your progress like this:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
// requestId is the WorkRequest id
.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(requestId)
.observe(observer, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
        if (workInfo != null) {
            val progress = workInfo.progress
            val value = progress.getInt(Progress, 0)
            // Do something with progress information
        }
})
```

If you are using `WorkContinuation`, and want the overall percent, I have found the easiest is to use `workInfosLiveData` like this:

```
WorkContinuation.combine(workForSyncingFlights).also {
it.enqueue()
it.workInfosLiveData.asFlow().conflate().collect { listOfWorkInfo ->
    if (listOfWorkInfo.isNullOrEmpty()) return@collect
    listOfWorkInfo.forEach { workInfo ->
        if (workInfo.state.isFinished) {
            val finished = listOfWorkInfo.filter { info -> info.state.isFinished }.size
            val totalPercent = finished.toDouble().div(listOfWorkInfo.size.toDouble()) * 100
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two additional infos from the very good Google documentation.

a) If you came here because you can not run your task without viewmodelscope.launch, take a look at Android "[Threading in WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker)" documentation.

b) The issue here can probably be solved with "[Observing intermediate Worker progress](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress)".