# How can a Worker communicate with the ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app where I want to update some data stored in the View Model at some intervals while the app is off, with Work Manager. However, I believe the View Model is not supposed to observe data, and I cannot get the instance of the View Model from inside the Worker's doWork() function. How do I call View Model functions from inside the doWork() function?

Here's some code in case it helps, this is in my ViewModel class:

```
fun setTestWorkRequest(){
     val task = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundPriceUpdater::class.java).build()
     WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(task)
}
```

And this is my Worker class:

```
class BackgroundPriceUpdater(context: Context,params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context,params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            return Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception){
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call the view model inside work manager. Instead create a singleton object and call it that

Answer (score 0):

You can have the worker [return data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params), and your `ViewModel` can read / observe the results and update itself. See, e.g., [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205578/17994624).